# Postgres ERROR: Unable to generate pre-signed url,

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I am trying to copy `Csv` file( which is inside an S3 bucket), to an AWS Postgres DB.
I am trying to run this `copy command`.

```
select aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
    'dump',
    '',
    '(format csv, escape ''"'')',
    's3://bucketname/Sample_Data.csv',
    '',
    'ap-southeast-1')
    ;"""
```

This is the error I am getting :

```
 ERROR: Unable to generate pre-signed url
```

This is the RDS log file

```
Attempting to validate pre-signed URL. 6 attempt(s) remaining. CURL error code 2 with message Could not resolve host: s3%3A%2F%2F%2FSample_Data.csv.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com.
2022-08-02 07:11:47:postgres@postgres:[3797]:STATEMENT: select aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
'dump',
'',
'(format csv)',
's3://bucketname/Sample_Data.csv',
'',
'ap-southeast-1')
```

Answer (score 1):

I had simmilar issue couple day ago and it turned out to be the security outbound&network route issue.

when I execute the sql, I used the structure like below.

SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3 (
..same...
aws_commons.create_s3_uri('','', 'ap-southeast-1'));

if the error message is still occurring after that, I suggest setting up s3 vpc endpoint for the rds instance.
even after setting up vpc endpoint for s3 if it's still not working,
you might want to check the security group setting for RDS instance.(outbound)

check out the steps on the post below. seems like covers all that I mentioned.
https://medium.com/@shobhita.agarwal/load-data-from-s3-to-rds-across-aws-accounts-e74c41c4a231

regards,
sungwon